# Where does Grails 2.1.0 / Java 7 get the current user name from on Windows 8.1?

Tags: java, grails, grails-2.0

I need to use Grails 2.1.0 (specifically that version) and have installed this on Java 7 (ditto specific version) by extracting it to "C:\Users\new.username\grails\grails-2.1.0\grails-2.1.0"  Unfortunately when I run grails I get an error as follows:

```
C:\>grails
Caching deactivated: failed to create cache directory: C:\Users\old.username\.grails

Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

This seems to show that either Grails or Java is picking up an old user name that Windows was created with and I need to know where this is being gotten from and how to change it to my current user "new.username" ?

I have looked through the registry and removed everything I dare that had old.username in it but am too scared to remove everything...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It's available in the environment, and you can access the values via `System.getenv()`. Both HOMEPATH and USERPROFILE point to my home directory when I tried this just now on a Windows machine, and my username showed up in USERPROFILE, LOCALAPPDATA, USERNAME, and APPDATA.

I recommend a ceremonial destruction by fire and the purchase of a Linux-based laptop, but not in that order.

Comment: I checked my complete environment and there is no reference to "old.username" whatsoever. In particular HOMEPATH, LOCALAPPDATA, APPDATA, USERNAME and USERPROFILE all refer to "new.username".  Thanks for your reply,

Comment: @Boo could it be in your $PATH (or what ever windows uses) so that the wrong grails.bat gets picked up and deduces the old location?  i'd use `which grails` on unix... dunno about windows

Comment: @cfrick: It's not my PATH variable, I have pasted my complete environment into an editor and searched for old.username and it is not used in the environment.  I believe it must be stashed away somewhere by Java but I have no clue where it could be...